# django url template tag - module not found error

Tags: django, django-templates

Django seems to be categorically rejecting ALL of my url template tags.

Whenever I run a page, in this case /accounts/login/, I get the following error:

```
Caught ViewDoesNotExist while rendering: Tried user_profile in module cozcus.views. Error was: 'module' object has no attribute 'form'
```

The django error pages then proceed to point out the url tags as where things went wrong.

Here's what I know: it's not a problem with the syntax of the url tags, as that would normally return:

```
Reverse for 'proyName.view_aboutPage' with arguments '()' and keyword 
arguments '{}' not found."
```

There was another question about this error on this website, which can be found [here,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733435/django-url-template-tag-module-object-has-no-attribute-views) but what went wrong was that there was a URL setting that pointed to a page that didn't exist.  I checked all of my urls, and they all point to existing views.

Does anyone have anything else i could try?  Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Think you are importing a form somewhere where you have inherited

```
forms.form
```

instead of

```
forms.Form
```

(Capital F).

Comment: Did the same mistake earlier today actually so that annoying, totally useless error message was still hard burned on my retinas :)